# AWS Key management service CLI commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-lambda, key-management, amazon-kms

**I am using command :**

```
put-key-policy --key-id <keyid> --policy-name <default> --policy <value>
```

**I get the error**

> MalformedPolicyDocumentException

I think its because I didn’t understand the value `–policy` parameter takes. 
Any links I can refer?

Comment: @error2007s : can you help

Comment: How are you using --policy <value> value can you paste actual usage or what value are using there?

Comment: hey hi, Thanks for replying. 
aws kms put-key-policy --key-id <encryption-key id> --policy-name default  --policy arn:aws:iam::1234567890998:user/aws_administrator

I tried using IAM policy, a json file local address, tried to put the whole policy content. nothing worked. I am not sure if I am using it the right way.

Comment: How did you put the Json file local address? Can you add value you used there for --policy

Comment: sure. --policy C:\Users\ksharma11\Desktop\temp\getpolicy.json

Comment: Refer this doc https://github.com/armstrtw/Rawscli/blob/master/R/kms.R

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same thing myself and I hope this helps. This was done on a FreeBSD server, so windows users will have to make appropriate adjustments. If you run something like:

```
$ aws kms put-key-policy --generate-cli-skeleton
```

You'll get back a skeleton of what the cli is looking for as input:

```
{
   "KeyId": "", 
   "PolicyName": "", 
   "Policy": "", 
   "BypassPolicyLockoutSafetyCheck": true
}
```

Meaning that the allowable input is a piece of JSON with up to 4 possible parameters. In this case we're looking to create a new policy so the only one we really need is `"Policy"`. What's required is a JSON policy in the form of a string. Using the following as an example:

```
{
 "Version" : "2012-10-17",
 "Id" : "key-consolepolicy-3"
}
```

First escape the double quotes, giving:

```
{
 \"Version\" : \"2012-10-17\",
 \"Id\" : \"key-consolepolicy-3\"
}
```

Then replace the newlines by `\n` characters, giving:

```
{\n \"Version\" : \"2012-10-17\",\n \"Id\" : \"key-consolepolicy-3\"\n }
```

And then we put this into double quotes:

```
"{\n \"Version\" : \"2012-10-17\",\n \"Id\" : \"key-consolepolicy-3\"\n }"
```

And finally our file looks like this:

```
{
  "Policy" : "{\n \"Version\" : \"2012-10-17\",\n \"Id\" : \"key-consolepolicy-3\"\n }"
}
```

If you already have a key with a policy you'd like to use then you can simply retrieve it:

```
$ aws kms get-key-policy --policy-name default --key-id XXXXXXXXX > policy
```

Whichever way you create it, you can then use the policy in the file to update the policy for the new key:

```
$ aws kms put-key-policy --key-id YYYYYYYY --policy-name default --cli-input-json file://policy
```

On Windows, the "`file://policy`" would be something like: "`file://C:\path\to\policyfile.json`"

If you're going to use the `--policy` command line argument rather than a policy in a file, `--policy` is also looking for a JSON policy in the form of a string, so you need

```
$ aws kms put-key-policy --key-id YYYYYYYY --policy-name default --policy "{\n \"Version\" : \"2012-10-17\",\n \"Id\" : \"key-consolepolicy-3\"\n }"
```